# Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, rest

We need to implement the API on the site, chose the REST framework. Auto-cutting done through Token (`rest_framework.authtoken`)

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
     'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
         'Rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
     ),
     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
         'Rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
       
     ),

}
```

view.py

```
   @api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def task_list(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        tasks = Task.objects.all()
        serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Gives an error message

```
"Detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

How to fix this error and prevent the GET method

Comment: you can put some if logic in the view for `request.user.is_authenticated` and avoid going into the GET block, etc... that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `TokenAuthentication` you need to set http request's header `Authorization: Token <user_token>`.

If you want some view to be allowed for any users you can specify permission class [AllowAny](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#allowany) for this view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def example_view(request, format=None):
    content = {
        'status': 'request was permitted'
    }
    return Response(content)
```

You can generate valid token using `obtain_auth_token` view. Add this to your urls.py:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token)
]
```

Comment: I do not need `AllowAny`, I need access to Token

Comment: @Sonfire you need to generate token? I update my answer, check it.

Comment: I have a TOKEN generated. I present it in the header of `token: ******`.
Gives an error message

Comment: @Sonfire is header has this format `Authorization: Token ****`?

Comment: @Sonfire this is incorrect. You should provide token with request header, not with GET arguments. Try to use soft like postman to build API request.

Comment: Good. And what about the POST method? I do so
http://prntscr.com/fq399e

Comment: @Sonfire you are doing it in request body. Open header part. And on the left textbox enter header key name `Authorization` and on the right enter header value `Token ***`. Word token is also part of header value.

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I completely close (globally) the GET API?

Comment: @Sonfire you are welcome! You can make allowed only POST method for endpoint with this decorator: `@api_view(['POST'])` just remove GET from it.

Comment: I wanted the error to be issued when referring to the GET as it is with `obtain_auth_token`

Comment: @Sonfire I dont remember what `get_auth_token` return to GET request, but if you remove GET from `@api_view` it will return 405 Method Not Allowed.

Comment: `get_auth_token` return access is denied (`{"detail": "Method \" GET \ "not allowed."}`).
And if you remove from me the GET method, then just return a 401 error

Comment: @Sonfire `get_auth_token` is class based view. probably this is the reson. Try to implement your view with APIView class without get method in it. Sorry that cannot help you more. See example here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views